# Accessing a {member of vector} of a {vector of a friendly class}

Tags: c++, vector, member, friend

I wanted to create a class (Army) that consists of a vector of another class (Human). When trying to access a member of Human through Army I ran into a Segmentation fault.

The following code is reduced to the necessary:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Human {
    private:
         vector <int> hair;
    public:
        //The size of the reserved entries is arbitrary.
        Human () {hair.reserve(12);}
        friend class Army;
        int get_hair(int a) {return hair[a];}

};
class Army {
    private:
        vector <Human> armyVec;
    public:
        //The size of the reserved entries is arbitrary.
        Army () {armyVec.reserve(12);}
        Human get_Human(int a) {return armyVec[a];}
};

int main()
{
    Human Viktor;
    Army Sparta;
    cout << Viktor.get_hair(1) << endl; //OK
    Viktor = Sparta.get_Human(2);
    cout << Viktor.get_hair(1) << endl; //OK
    //Now I want to access it directly:
```

> ```
>   cout << Sparta.get_Human(2).get_hair(1) << endl;    //Segfault !!!
> ```

```
    cout << "Done" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0
0
Segmentation fault
```

It works when "hair" isn't a vector but for example an integer (with changes accordingly). How can one solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: `reserve()` doesn't change the size of the vector. The vector is still empty. An attempt to access any element, at any index, therefore exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Use `resize()` instead of `reserve()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reserve` only reserves capacity (aka memory) to hold a number of elements. No elements is added to the `vector`. You can use `resize` to add elements.

This little program shows the difference between `reserve`, `capacity`, `resize` and `size`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.reserve(10);
    std::cout << "Vector capacity after reserve: " << a.capacity() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vector size after reserve: " << a.size() << std::endl;
    a.resize(5);
    std::cout << "Vector capacity after resize: " << a.capacity() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vector size after resize: " << a.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Vector capacity after reserve: 10
Vector size after reserve: 0
Vector capacity after resize: 10
Vector size after resize: 5
```

You use `reserve` when you know that the vector over time will grow to a certain size and you want to avoid multiple memory allocations/copies as it grows. In other words - reserving capacity up front, may improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

### It works when "hair" isn't a vector but for example an integer (with changes accordingly). How can one solve this?

It works when we use the "int hair" instead of Vector only when we use "**static** int hair". Even though the Human object is not initialised in Army, the "static int" value  will always be available over the class(strictly typed here).